# Aggregate the nested object within every document

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with the following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "000aaa111",
    "reviewer_id" : "KQ5E8vKN5ezzgwH3C",
    "reviewee_id" : "FodX5fCg3RBe92Dpu",
    "stars" : [
        {
            "val" : "4.5",
            "for" : "communication"
        }, 
        {
            "val" : "4",
            "for" : "cleanliness"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is actually for rating an item where my visitor will give them star (1 to 5). So how do I be able to aggregate the whole documents that I have in a collection as to summarize all the star received. This is the output that I expect

```
{
    "reviewee_id": "FodX5fCg3RBe92Dpu",
    "overall": "5",
    "communication": "3",
    "cleanliness": "3.5"
}
```

Mongodb is still quite new to me and I can't find any example that match with the structure I have right now.

Do you think my is good to go?

Comment: Do you mind  adding the expected output to to the post ?

Comment: oh yes. I have updated my question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the expected output, you'll need to adjust your structure to make best use of aggregation.

Your structure should look like.

**Input:**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("585dc520772c68234445f2a4"),
    "reviewer_id": "KQ5E8vKN5ezzgwH3C",
    "reviewee_id": "FodX5fCg3RBe92Dpu",
    "stars": [{
        "communication": 4.5
    }, {
        "cleanliness": 4
    }, {
        "overall": 3
    }]
} {
    "_id": ObjectId("585dc520772c68234445f2a2"),
    "reviewer_id": "KQ5E8vKN5ezzgwH3D",
    "reviewee_id": "FodX5fCg3RBe92Dpu",
    "stars": [{
        "communication": 2.5
    }, {
        "cleanliness": 3
    }, {
        "overall": 4
    }]
}
```

**Query:**

```
aggregate(
    [{
        $unwind: "$stars"
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$reviewee_id",
            communication: {
                $avg: "$stars.communication"
            },
            cleanliness: {
                $avg: "$stars.cleanliness"
            },
            overall: {
                $avg: "$stars.overall"
            }
        }
    }]
)
```

**Output**

```
{ "_id" : "FodX5fCg3RBe92Dpu", "communication" : 3.5, "cleanliness" : 3.5, "overall" : 3.5 }
```

Comment: I use meteor and I couldn't straight forward apply aggregation with meteor. Now am looking at `meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`